# I can't add Android Beacon Library to project

Tags: android, beacon

I want to develop a project using [Android-Beacon-Library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) in Android Studio, but I could not add the Library to the project.

I edited the build.gradle file as stated on the official site and the library shows up on the dependencies page. but I cannot access the classes in the library from the MainActivity class. I'm new to Android Studio please help

Comment: Please show your build.grade file as well as the output of your Android Studio Event Log that shows the results of the last gradle sync.  It should start with something like `2:37 Gradle sync started`.  You can force a new gradle sync by modifying your build.gradle file and tapping Sync Now in Android Studio.

Comment: As I said, I am new in Android Studio and I didn't know that I had to sync gradle. When I sync, my problem improved. Thank you